How to get a SQL script log in PostgreSQL
As a team of developers we only have access to the dev database to make changes in tables, views, etc. When it comes to the test, stage, and production environments we send the "SQL script" to the DBAs, so they can run it in the corresponding higher environments.
Unfortunately, the DBAs only gives us the execution log for the last SQL statement in the script since "this is a limitation of pgAdmin". We are in the dark about how the rest of the script went, even in prod.
For example if the SQL script has 5 SQL queries, as in:
insert into ...
delete from ...
insert into ...
update ...
update ...

The DBA only sends us back the following single log line (that we assume corresponds to the last query):
Query returned successfully in 78 msec

Is it possible to get the success/fail status of each query in the script, along with the number of affected rows, using pgAdmin or other tool?

If they really need to use pgadmin for this, ask them to run it in its psql tool not the query tool. The latter probably does show only the command tag of the last statement but they should be able to copy the whole session log from the former. You can also wrap all queries in explain analyze verbose to get not just the timings and row counts, but entire plans.

@Zegarek At this point I'm starting to question the use of pgAdmin to run scripts. We need a full log when to confirm the changes in prod. Other tools should be on the table as well. I'll look into query tool. Thanks.

See Query Tool in particular Query History Panel.

Write a single DO-statement that executes all statements and in between creates some NOTICEs with the details you want to know. There will be only one SQL statement for the DBA to execute and only the NOTICE to return to you

You can create a custom SQL script to execute each query in a block and capture the result. This method can return the status of each query and the number of rows affected. like bellow
INSERT INTO my_table (column1) VALUES ('value1') RETURNING id INTO v_result;
GET DIAGNOSTICS v_rows_affected = ROW_COUNT;
RAISE NOTICE 'Query 1 affected % rows', v_rows_affected;

